# How to reverse the layout order of a Row in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to replicate the UI of some messaging apps where the layout of the message content row is reversed if the sender is myself.

While I can do this:

```
if (sender != me) {
  Row(
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start
  ) {
    AvatarComposable()
    TextMessageComposable()
    TimestampComposable()
  }
} else {
  Row(
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End
  ) {
    TimestampComposable()
    TextMessageComposable()
    AvatarComposable()
  }
}
```

But I see this is doing a lot of repetitive work. Are there any better way to do this?

Comment: See also https://blog.logrocket.com/create-custom-layouts-android-apps-jetpack-compose/ for a custom `ReverseFlowRow()` implementation.